# Oracle pass today's value to a variable and use it

Tags: sql, database, oracle, variables

I want to use today as a variable and use it in a query like this:

```
  select record_date, 
         another_column
    from table
   where record_date = v_today
order by record_date;
```

Where `v_today` is the desired variable. How can I do it?

Comment: `where record_date = :v_today`? Here `:` (colon) marks `:v_today` as variable

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if your problem is in passing a variable, or in how to compare dates.  If you always want 'today', then there is no need to use a declared variable. Just use SYSDATE.  And since DATE and TIMESTAMPS always contain a time component, you need to strip that out with TRUNC:

```
select record_date,
       another_column
from my_table
where trunc(record_date) = trunc(sysdate)
;
```

If you want 'yesterday', then subtrace 1 (day) from sysdate:

```
select record_date,
           another_column
    from my_table
    where trunc(record_date) = trunc(sysdate - 1 )
    ;
```

Comment: `trunc(some_date) = trunc(sysdate)` would better utilise partitioning and indexes if it is written like `some_date >= trunc(sysdate) and some_date < trunc(sysdate + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter rows by today's date you can use `current_date`, as in:

```
select record_date, another_column
from table
where record_date = trunc(current_date)
order by record_date;
```

Comment: That doesn't allow for the time component inherent in the DATE or TIMESTAMP types. There is also no indication that the OP needs to consider current timezone, inherent in using CURRENT_DATE vs simply using SYSDATE.